# wso2am 2.2.0 publisher in HA setup

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

having 2 wso2am (2.2.0) nodes in a cluster (shared userstore, apimdb, registry, hazelcast cluster, server filesytem) - when I create API on one of the nodes, it is not visible  on another node, the nodes only see "their own" APIs. This is valid even after restarting the node, so it has nothing to do with caching :/

I can see all the APIs from both nodes  create in the database and registry. Any hint - what could I forget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug,
https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues/3484.

The fix is shipped with wum and APIM 2.5.0 release.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to do so (use a wummed version)

Comment: Thank you, using wummed version, lowercase simple API names and not disabling indexing helped :)